# How to ensure bootloader is started

Tags: embedded-linux, iot, bootloader, firmware

I am working with openmote-cc2538 for the project: https://github.com/cetic/6lbr/wiki

Here when I was trying to flash  openmote with this command

```
sudo make TARGET=cc2538dk BOARD=openmote-CC2538 bootload0/dev/ttyUSB0 slip-radio.upload
```

This error message is displayed

```
ERROR:Cant CONNECT TO TARGET:Ensure bootloader is started(no answer on sync sequence)
```

cc2538 bsl.py script is available for uploading binary to openmote. But I don't have much experience about this. Can anybody give me some suggestions regarding how to proceed??

Answer (score 0):

Grab a scope and probe different digital I/O pins on the CC2538. Typically a bootloader will initialize all the ports on the chip and you will see them change state, which is an indication that the bootloader is indeed running. I would guess one of the LEDs would change state as well (which doesn't require a scope).